# Optimize two dependent equations

Tags: matlab, optimization

I am trying to fit two curves that are dependent on each other. Following are the equations:

```
y1(t+1) = (param1 * y1(t) * (param2-y1(t))) + (param3 * y2(t) * (param2-y1(t)))

y2(t+1) = (param4 * y2(t) * (param5-y2(t))) + (param6 * y1(t) * (param5-y2(t)))
```

Our aim is to optimize the values of all the parameters such that we are able to model `y1` and `y2` sequence close to observed. We have ground truth to compute error (SSE).

How can we optimize two sets of questions that are dependent on each other? I have been looking at using MATLAB `lsqnonlin` but I am not sure how to optimize this.

Comment: Thanks for the response @m7913d. However, the link you shared fits one equation. This is the base case and works well. However, my question is how we can optimize when we have a dependency in the equations. As you see, value of y1(t+1) depends not only on y1(t) but also on y2(t). The other equation is symmetric but governed by different parameters.

Comment: Are you able to solve it when `y1(t+1)` only depends on `y1(t)`? If so, please show your code.